# how to use GeneratorFunction interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanted to use the generator function, and then I came across the generator function interface.

```
let foo: GeneratorFunction = function * () { return 1}
```

This raised the following error:

```
Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type '() => Generator<never, number, unknown>' but required in type 'GeneratorFunction'.(2741)
lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts(166, 14): '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is declared here.
```

Why is that?

Comment: Yes, it is. ...

Comment: @JonasWilms shouldn't it be `Generator`? EDIT: oops, misread it. `Generator` is what it returns.

Comment: @vlaz no, that should be the specific iterator returned by the generator function (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7c4c0a396203adb9ce5a989b61a04ac25657246e/lib/lib.es2015.generator.d.ts#L31)

Comment: In fact, it reported a mistake.

Comment: @JaredSmith that duplicate has answers that do not match the question in the title

Comment: @yuqing-zhang this one? Or a different one? Please in the future add the error directly to the question (otherwise we're all just guessing)

Comment: Yes, that's what I really want to ask : )

Comment: most of the time you should not use explicit types for your variables. Let TS to the job for you

Comment: so, how to use GeneratorFunction interface

Comment: I was just curious 

Comment: @Pointy while that is an exact duplicate, this still seems to be very strange behavior of Typescript. Why does GeneratorFunction have a Symbol.toStringTag whereas Functions do not?

Comment: FWIW if they had added `interface Object { [Symbol.toStringTag]?: string; }` 
 we wouldn't have this problem. [Also it seemed this was planned this way](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/980#issuecomment-60841971). Not sure why it was implemented differently in the end

Comment: I'm gonna add another answer to the duplicate and eventually I'm gonna raise an issue to Typescript